# Generate imagemagick / carrierwave thumbnails when they are requested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick, carrierwave

I am using the carrierwave gem with Rmagick in a Rails app. I've set up a new version in my uploader file:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base   
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  version :preview do
     process :resize_to_fill => [580, 350]
  end
end
```

Of course, I included rmagick and carrierwave in my gemfile. Now I try to load the *preview* version of my images in my views:

```
@product.photos.first.image.preview
```

This does not give any errors, but loads a broken image. If I copy the url of the image, I get a routing error ('no route matches /path/to_my_imagesfolder/preview_image.png'). If I remove the *preview* method, the image loads properly.

What can the problem be? I thought maybe it was a permissions issue, but I set the uploads folder with 777 and it still fails.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I realized if I upload the images again the new versions are created. Is it possible to make Rmagick create them when they are requested (like TimThumb does in PHP) Or at least is there any command to batch create all the versions?

There must be a better way than uploading all the images...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use .recreate_versions!

For example:

```
Product.all.each do |product|
  product.photos.each do |photo|
    photo.recreate_versions!
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice! But this creates them once this code is executed right? Do you know of any way to make this happen automatically, so each time a user requests a version that has not been created yet its recreated and served?

Comment: Just to follow this up, no I'm not sure this is possible. It shouldn't cause too many load issues unless you're uploading images all the time. So having the generate thumbs on uploads is generally fine.

Comment: You are probably right. I think i will do that and create a task for whenever I create new versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use this: https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly